# I can't save a list

Tags: python-3.x, save

```
import tkinter as tk

list = []

def add():
    element = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0, 1000)
    list.append(element)

def save():
    with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
        for element in list:
            f.write(element + ",")

root = tk.Tk()

frameList = tk.Frame(root)
frameList.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

btnAdd = tk.Button(root, text="add", command=add)
btnAdd.pack(pady=5)

btnSave = tk.Button(root, text="save", command=save)
btnSave.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this code give me this error when I save:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/python/github/write.py", line 11, in save
    with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'save.txt'
```

and if I create the file "save.txt" it says:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/python/github/write.py", line 13, in save
    f.write(element + ",")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

please, can you help me to solve this problem?

sorry for this last sentence but I have to add some "not code" to publish the question, so I will say some random stuff from now, sorry

Comment: `No such file or directory: 'save.txt'` literally means what it says. The file `save.txt` does not exist in the current working directory. Also, the code does not match the error. The traceback shows `with open("save.txt") as f:` but the code shows `with open("save.txt", "w") as f:`.

Comment: If you try the code by yourself, even on the website, it saves a new file and it qrite it

Comment: Regardless, if python is giving you a `No such file or directory` error, that's precisely what it means: you've given it a filename that can't be found.

Comment: Yeah but if I create it, it gives the other error

Comment: Have you tried the code?